# Color bars according to specific value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to create a panel of bar plots. In each panel, I am comparing the percentage of grouped probabilities (x-axis) against the probability from a previous time. What I want to do is highlight the column within each panel that matches the panel. For example, in the upper left panel of the output shown below, I want the 0.0 to 2.0 column to be highlighted since it matches that panel. In the second panel of row one, I want the .21 to .40 column to be highlighted, etc. I would also like all columns below that one to be one color, and all columns above it to be another color.

Code:

```
g3 <- ggplot(passQ2, aes(probcatq2))
g3 + geom_bar(aes(weight=PCT_ROW),position="dodge",width=.75) +
  facet_wrap( ~ area+probcatq1,ncol=5,labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line=FALSE)) + 
  geom_text(data=countsp2, aes(x=3,y=85,label=n,group=NULL), size=2) +
  labs(x="Probability Category",y="Percent") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,80,20)) + 
  scale_fill_grey() + 
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, size=8),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(size=8))
```

[This is what my output looks like in grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owKo6.jpg)

Comment: Add a column to your data indicating whether each row is a member of a column you want highlighted. Then map `fill` to that column inside `aes`.

Comment: Something like `passQ2$filled <- passQ2$probatq1 == passQ2$probatq2`, an then `geom_bar(aes(fill = filled, ...), ...)`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Gregor and @Axeman!